# Parsing a boost::variant with User Defined Datatype containing std::string using Spirit Qi

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to create a GPIB parser using Spirit.Qi. Sometimes the response can
be either an error or a normal response. This seemed like a good use case for
the alternative parser which yields a `boost::variant`; however, if one of the
variant types contains a string the code fails to compile. Here is a simplified
version that reproduces the error.

```
struct C1 {
   std::string h{""};
   int i{0};
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(C1, (std::string, h)(int, i))

struct C2 {
   std::string h{""};
   std::string c{};
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(C2, (std::string, h)(std::string, c))

using VariantType = boost::variant<C1, C2>;

int main() {
   std::string s2{"C2:Zoo3"};
   VariantType v1;
   if(qi::parse(s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
                (qi::string("C1") >> ":" >> qi::int_) | 
                (qi::string("C2") >> ":" >> *qi::char_), 
                v1)) {
      if(boost::get<C1>(&v1)) {
         auto a1 = boost::get<C1>(v1);
         std::cout << "Parsing Succeeded, a1 = " << a1.h << ":" 
                   << a1.i << std::endl;
      }
      else {
         auto a2 = boost::get<C2>(v1);
         std::cout << "Parsing Succeeded, a2 = " << a2.h << ":" 
                   << a2.c << std::endl;
      }
   }
   else {
      std::cout << "Parsing Failed" << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I've experimented with various parsers other than `*qi::char_` (eg. `qi::string`) to no avail. If I change `C2::c` to a `char` it works ok for 1 char. The best workaround I have found so far is to change `C2::c` to a `std::vector<char>`, this works fine but isn't ideal. I also tried telling Qi that `std::string` is a container like [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/custom_string.cpp). But qi knows what a `std::string` is so I'm pretty sure it ignores my customization. I think this is all because `std::string` isn't a POD and wasn't supported in unions until the rules were relaxed, but it works with `boost::variant` when it isn't in a struct, and `std::vector` works. Any ideas/workarounds would be appreciated.

*Note: I didn't post the compiler errors as they are long and mangled and I figured this was a known issue of `std::string` and variants. If they would be helpful let me know and I'll post them.

Comment: Qi knows what a string is, so the customization is redundant: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/508941b22ad5bc1d. POD-ness is certainly not required (what would be the purpose of Boost Variant?). (Don't call `variant`s unions, it's unnecessarily confusing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code, as far as I can tell.

I've tested on c++1{1,4,y} and boost 1.{57,58}.0, using gcc {4.9,5.x} and clang++ 3.5.

I suspect you may have an awkward Boost verion. Try using `qi::as_string[*qi::char_]` there. ¹

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc216e0a89fdd17e)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct C1 {
   std::string h{""};
   int i{0};

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, C1 const& c1) {
       return os << "C1 {h:'" << c1.h << "', i:'" << c1.i << "'}";
   }
};

struct C2 {
   std::string h{""};
   std::string c{};

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, C2 const& c2) {
       return os << "C2 {h:'" << c2.h << "', c:'" << c2.c << "'}";
   }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(C1, (std::string, h)(int, i))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(C2, (std::string, h)(std::string, c))

using VariantType = boost::variant<C1, C2>;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    VariantType value;
    for(std::string s1 : {
            "C2:Zoo3",
            "C1:1234"
            })
    {
        if(qi::parse(s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
                    (qi::string("C1") >> ":" >> qi::int_) | 
                    (qi::string("C2") >> ":" >> *qi::char_), 
                    value)) 
            std::cout << "Parsing Succeeded: " << value << "\n";
        else             
            std::cout << "Parsing Failed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsing Succeeded: C2 {h:'C2', c:'Zoo3'}
Parsing Succeeded: C1 {h:'C1', i:'1234'}
```

---

¹ I don't recommend `qi::attr_cast<>` as I remember this having had an awkward bug in awkwardly old boost versions.

Comment: Here it is even [with g++-4.6 -std=c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d419eb1d1ba6f1d0)

Comment: Thanks sehe. Your code works, and so does mine in fact. The code I posted was one of 4 test cases. After I tried it by itself it worked, so I'm still not sure what the problem was. I need to look into it more. I apologize for not having tested just the code I posted, that was careless. Because of all the weirdness I was seeing I convinced myself it had to do with unions and strings. Also I am using gcc 4.9.2 (work) 5.1 (home) and boost 1.58. Thanks for the quick response, I really appreciate your contributions to SO. Your response let me know this was doable.